# getting username and email from firestore in reactnative mobileapplication

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get current login username and email from firestore, but it throws an error.

The code:

```
firestore()
  .collection('users')
  .get(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
  .then(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    })
  });
```

I write this code and it throws an error:

> Error: firebase.firestore().collection().get(*) 'options' must be an object is provided., js engine: hermes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to [load a single document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document) based on the user ID, that'd be:

```
firestore()
  .collection('users')
  .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
  .get()
  .then(doc => {
    console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
  });
```

The change here is that we pass the UID to a function called `doc()` to build a reference to the correct document, and we then call `get()` on that document reference without any arguments.

Comment: Thank u very much this code works

Answer (score 0):

you are passing an invalid argument to get() method

```
get(options?: GetOptions): Promise<DocumentSnapshot<>>;
```

GetOptions type

```
{
   source: "default" | "server" | "cache";
}
```

ref: https://rnfirebase.io/reference/firestore/documentreference#get